# PHP comment box to txt file

Tags: php

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <form method="post">
   <textarea name="txt" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea>
   <br><br> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />

   <?php
   if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
     $com  = $_POST[ "txt" ];
     $file = fopen( "weather.txt", "a" );
     fwrite( $file, "<br>" );
     for ( $i = 0; $i <= strlen( $com ) - 1; $i++ ) {
       fwrite( $file, $com[ $i ] );
         if ( $i % 37 == 0 && $i != 0 ) fwrite( $file, "<br/>" );
       }
       fwrite( $file, "<br>------------------------------------------" );
       fclose( $file );
       // Add here
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="";</script>'; 
     }
   ?>

   <br>
  </form>
  <font face="Times New Roman"><b><p>Textul introdus este: </p></b></font>
  <font face="Comic Sans MS" color="red" size="2">
  <?php
    if (file_exists("weather.txt")) {
    $file = fopen( "weather.txt", "r" );
    echo fread( $file, filesize( "weather.txt" ) );
      fclose( $file );
    }
   ?>
   </font>
 </body>
</html>
```

This code works fine to add text to the weather.txt file.

But what I need is: When you hit submit it does not add the new text to the old text,  it deletes the old text and only puts in the new text. (In other words I do not what the old text to stay once the new text is added).

Comment: Now you edited the question several times and now I don't understand any more what you really want ;)

Comment: @MrTux the only editing that's been done was my making the indenting consistant, not right shifted, and moving one comment to a new line to remove a horizontal scroll.

Comment: An observation: don't use `<font>` tags. They have been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT) for a long time and no longer exist in `HTML5`. You can use `<p>` or `<span>` with `CSS` styling instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fopen( "weather.txt", "w" );` instead of `fopen( "weather.txt", "a" );`. The `w` makes PHP open the file for writing only and resetting the writing pointer to the beginning of the file (i.e., you're overriding it).

See `mode` explanation on http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php for more details.

Comment: Hi @Todd if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`a` in the `fopen` is for append, so in current code use `w` to overwrite.  However I would simplify:

```
if(isset($_POST[ 'submit' ])) {
     $com = $_POST[ "txt" ];
     $content  = "<br>" . chunk_split($com, 37, "<br>") . "<br>";
     $content .= "------------------------------------------";
     file_put_contents("weather.txt", $content);
}
```

And then later to display:

```
if(file_exists("weather.txt")) {
    echo file_get_contents("weather.txt");
    //or alternately
    readfile("weather.txt");
}
```

Comment: Ok the chunk_split is there way to do this so it dont split the word once it gets to 37 that it moves the whole word down the line.

Comment: Ok i got it working now,   I just changed 

$content  = "<br>" . chunk_split($com, 37, "<br>") . "<br>";
To
$content  = "<br>" . chunk_split($com) . "<br>";

and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

`fopen("weather.txt","w")` for **w** rite instead of **a** ppend.

or

`file_put_contents("weather.txt",$yourContent)`